# .htaccess file isn't applying itself and doesn't work unless I edit httpd.conf

Tags: centos, .htaccess

I have a CentOS server I just setup, and I set the `DocumentRoot` in the httpd.conf file as

```
/var/www/html/SITENAME
```

and that works fine.

The `/var/www/html/SITENAME/.htaccess` rules inside that folder are not working/applying themselves unless I put .htaccess rules in the httpd.conf file, in which case it works.

How do I make the .htaccess rules in that folder actually apply themselves so when I visit www.SITENAME.com the .htaccess file works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using AllowOverride none in your httpd.conf file